# Getting back "star" option to nautilus right click menu

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 22.10, context-menu

Recent updates of Nautilus removed the "star" option from right click menu, and to star a file you have to switch to "list view" and click on star on the far right coloumn.

I frequently use star option for my files and I mostly use nautlius in "grid view".

Is that a way to have star option in right click menu back so that I don't need to switch to list view, star the file, and switch back to the grid view?

Ubuntu 22.10, Gnome 43.1, Gnome Nautilus 43.0

Comment: as 22.10 is an interim release, you should report it as a bug. https://login.launchpad.net/mkQ7B0sCjtR3JaTO/+decide